# How to iterate index in Javascript using forEach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to iterate this object. I have checked code over the internet and found that Object.enteries can work but so far it is only returning 1st CustomerName i.e. "Asad". I want to iterate it to the complete array not just the first one.

```
var myObject = {
        "records": [
            {
                "id": "recDBqsW7C3Dk3HMd",
                "fields": {
                    "Latitude": "24.898907",
                    "Longitude": "67.117303",
                    "CustomerName": "Asad"
                },
                "createdTime": "2020-10-07T04:43:31.000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": "recGlfTbUcEvP46Lf",
                "fields": {
                    "Latitude": "24.907641",
                    "Longitude": "67.1088035",
                    "CustomerName": "Umar"
                },
                "createdTime": "2020-10-07T04:44:11.000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": "recfsQsoznDyWPDe8",
                "fields": {
                    "Latitude": "24.911112",
                    "Longitude": "67.105117",
                    "CustomerName": "Ali"
                },
                "createdTime": "2020-10-06T09:11:05.000Z"
            }
        ]
    };
    
    
    Object.entries(myObject).forEach(([key, value], index) => {
      console.log( value[index].fields.CustomerName); // key ,value
    });
```

Result:

```
"Asad"
```

Comment: There's only one entry in `myObject`, and its property name is "records".

Comment: `index` is an index into `myObject` properties, why are you using it as an index for `value`?

Comment: How can I change this code to iterate every "CustomerName".

Answer (score 2):

The array is actually a property of the object literal you defined it in. All you need to do is access that array and call `Array.prototype.forEach` on it in order to access it's elements. Something like this:

```js
//Extract the array from your data structure into a variable. Always use 
//a const if the variable will not need to be re-assigned in the program.
const {
  records
} = {
  "records": [{
      "id": "recDBqsW7C3Dk3HMd",
      "fields": {
        "Latitude": "24.898907",
        "Longitude": "67.117303",
        "CustomerName": "Asad"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-10-07T04:43:31.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "recGlfTbUcEvP46Lf",
      "fields": {
        "Latitude": "24.907641",
        "Longitude": "67.1088035",
        "CustomerName": "Umar"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-10-07T04:44:11.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "recfsQsoznDyWPDe8",
      "fields": {
        "Latitude": "24.911112",
        "Longitude": "67.105117",
        "CustomerName": "Ali"
      },
      "createdTime": "2020-10-06T09:11:05.000Z"
    }
  ]
};

//Iterate over the items in the array to access the data you need
records.forEach(record => {
  console.log(`${record.id} = ${record.fields.CustomerName}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you are using the wrong approach here.

The thing that you need to do is:

```js
var myObject = {
        "records": [
            {
                "id": "recDBqsW7C3Dk3HMd",
                "fields": {
                    "Latitude": "24.898907",
                    "Longitude": "67.117303",
                    "CustomerName": "Asad"
                },
                "createdTime": "2020-10-07T04:43:31.000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": "recGlfTbUcEvP46Lf",
                "fields": {
                    "Latitude": "24.907641",
                    "Longitude": "67.1088035",
                    "CustomerName": "Umar"
                },
                "createdTime": "2020-10-07T04:44:11.000Z"
            },
            {
                "id": "recfsQsoznDyWPDe8",
                "fields": {
                    "Latitude": "24.911112",
                    "Longitude": "67.105117",
                    "CustomerName": "Ali"
                },
                "createdTime": "2020-10-06T09:11:05.000Z"
            }
        ]
    };

myObject.records.forEach((value, index) => {
      console.log( value.fields.CustomerName); // key ,value
 });
```

By doing so you will iterate through your records easily and get all names.

What you currently are doing is iterating trough the key-value pairs of the `myObject` where `Object.entries(myObject)` will return to you `[['records', [array of the users]]]` then the `console.log` in the `forEach` block will be called once, as you have only one entry there.

Comment: myObject is not defined

Comment: Run the snippet now

Answer (score 0):

Try this code please. It finds the `keys` and then iterates with `forEach`

```
for (var key of Object.keys(myObject)) {
   myObject[key].forEach((v) => {
     console.log(v.fields.CustomerName)
   })
}
```